# Duplicate Query in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, duplicates, ms-access-2007

I am trying to run a query to find duplicates in a table on Field1.  However, I would like to limit my query to duplicates where at least one (but not necessarily both) of the duplicate records fit a certain criteria like being "not null" or like "foo" in Field2.

The original duplicate query is easy, but I am unsure how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

In (SELECT [Field1] FROM [Table] As Tmp GROUP BY [Feild1] HAVING Count(*)>1 )

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `WHERE` clause to tell the db engine to ignore certain rows *before* it processes the `GROUP BY`, which means those rows will be excluded from the `Count`.

I'm unsure whether I understood the criteria for which rows to ignore, but will offer this as a starting point ...

```sql
SELECT tmp.[Field1]
FROM [Table] As Tmp
WHERE
        tmp.Field1 Is Not Null
    AND NOT (tmp.Field2 ALike '%foo%')
GROUP BY tmp.[Field1]
HAVING Count(*)>1;
```

Some notes about `ALike`:

`ALike` is valid in Access SQL.  It signals the db engine to expect ANSI wild card characters, `%` and `_`, instead of the non-standard Access wild cards `*` and `?`.

Within an Access application session, you may be accustomed to `Like '*foo*'`, and that generally works.  However, if you're running a query from ADO within an Access session, or have selected the database option to use *"SQL Server Compatible Syntax (ANSI 92)"*, you must use the standard ANSI wild cards: `Like '%foo%'`.  Also, from outside an Access session using OleDb to connect to the db file, you must use the standard ANSI wild cards.

In summary, `Like` requires different wild cards depending on context.  However, `ALike` *always* uses the standard ANSI wild cards regardless of context.  So, with `ALike`, an Access query will operate the same regardless of where and how you use it.

Comment: My apologies, and thanks for the information. I wasn't aware of ALike and just thought it was a typo. I'm surprised I haven't come across this before, as it is a very good idea.

Comment: No worries, I make plenty typos but that wasn't one of them.  :-)  `ALike` isn't well known, so I should probably add an explanation by default when suggesting it.  But I were lazy ...

Comment: I suppose we'll have to keep some default text somewhere so we can include it whenever we use `ALike`, doh. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a `CASE` statement in a `WHERE` clause, something like this:

```
SELECT Field1
FROM Table

WHERE 1 =
CASE
    WHEN Field1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1
    WHEN Field1 LIKE '%foo%' THEN 1
    ELSE 0   -- Otherwise, don't include in result set.
END

GROUP BY Field1
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: `CASE ... WHEN` is not available in Access SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Using a nested query we can limit the records to those which are duplicates,and then we can filter to find those records which meet the additional Criteria on Field 2

```
SELECT [Field1],[Field2] FROM
[Table] where
(Field2 is NOT NULL OR Field2 like '%foo%') -- Add additional conditions here
AND Field1 IN
    (SELECT [Field1] FROM [Table] As Tmp GROUP BY [Feild1] HAVING Count(*) > 1 )
```